# Qt3D texture parameter

Tags: c++, qt3d

I am using Qt3D (5.11), and I am experiencing asserts when I try to set a `QParameter` value to be used by a custom fragment shader. Here is the section of code that doesn't seem to be working:

```
auto entity = new Qt3DRender::QEntity( mRootEntity );
auto material = new Qt3DRender::QMaterial( entity );

// Set up the custom geometry and material for the entity, which works
// fine in tests as long as the fragment shader does not use texture mapping

auto image = new Qt3DRender::QTextureImage( entity );
image->setSource( QString( "qrc:/image.png" ) );

auto texture = new Qt3DRender::QTexture2D( entity );
texture->addTextureImage( image );

material->addParameter( new QParameter( "imageTexture", texture, entity ) );
```

I've included only the bits of code needed for this question:

Is this a valid way to set a simple texture parameter? If not, what am I missing to set a simple image?

Note that `qrc:/image.png` is a 256x256 image that I have used elsewhere in this project without a problem.

The code compiles fine, but when I run it I get an assert with the following message: `ASSERT: "texture" in file texture\textureimage.cpp, line 94`

I am using VS2017 on Windows 10 with Qt 5.11.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon the issue. Parenting the `QTextureImage` to `entity` leads to the assert. Leaving off the parent completely (effectively setting it to `nullptr`) or parenting it to `texture` fixes the issue.

Here is some working code:

```
auto texture = new Qt3DRender::QTexture2D( entity );
auto image = new Qt3DRender::QTextureImage( texture );
image->setSource( QString( "qrc:/image.png" ) );
texture->addTextureImage( image );

material->addParameter( new QParameter( "imageTexture", texture, entity ) );
```

This is probably a bug? If someone knows why the `QTextureImage` cannot be safely parented to `entity`, please add a comment.